# Tuple key logic order of Counter most_common()

Tags: python

I found out that my algorithm is depended on order of `Counter.most_common()` applied to the dictionary.

```
d = {(2, -3, -5): 13, (1, -3, -5): 10, (3, 4, -5): 5, (-1, -3, -4): 13, (-3, -4, -5): 15, (3, -4, 5): 9, (-1, 2, -3): 15, (-1, 2, -4): 15, (2, -4, -5): 12, (1, -2, -5): 9, (-1, 2, -5): 14, (-2, 4, 5): 7, (-1, 4, 5): 10, (-2, -3, -5): 10, (-1, 3, 5): 13, (-2, 3, 5): 11, (2, 4, 5): 6, (-1, 2, 4): 11, (1, -2, 4): 8, (-2, 3, -4): 9, (-1, 3, -4): 12, (-3, -4, 5): 4, (-1, -2, -5): 7}
output = dict(Counter(d).most_common())
```

output:

```
{(-3, -4, -5): 15, (-1, 2, -3): 15, (-1, 2, -4): 15, (-1, 2, -5): 14, (2, -3, -5): 13, (-1, -3, -4): 13, (-1, 3, 5): 13, (2, -4, -5): 12, (-1, 3, -4): 12, (-2, 3, 5): 11, (-1, 2, 4): 11, (1, -3, -5): 10, (-1, 4, 5): 10, (-2, -3, -5): 10, (3, -4, 5): 9, (1, -2, -5): 9, (-2, 3, -4): 9, (1, -2, 4): 8, (-2, 4, 5): 7, (-1, -2, -5): 7, (2, 4, 5): 6, (3, 4, -5): 5, (-3, -4, 5): 4}
```

This sorts values, but key order is very strange and doesn't always equal to sorted() or sorted() in reversed order, however it's determined and doesn't depended on order of initial dictionary. I know that this structure is unordered, but I need to figurate what is pattern of printing and fetching the most right element.

Comment: Your `output` is not matching my output though from running that code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming Python version >= 3.7 (>=3.6 with CPython) then dicts do retain insertion order. This is `Counter()`'s [documented behaviour](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) (bold emphasis mine):

> Return a list of the n most common elements and their counts from the
> most common to the least. If n is omitted or None, most_common()
> returns all elements in the counter. **Elements with equal counts are
> ordered in the order first encountered**:

Comment: Feel myself stupid, I saw docs about this but wan't able to prove by experiment. In the end, I've got that other thing (itertools.combinations) was responsible for output change.